# .htaccess redirect displaying urlslug variable

Tags: .htaccess

I had a page on my website that utilised .htaccess redirect

Page

```
/folder/page-name.php
```

.htaccess

```
/folder/(.*).php /code/page.php?urlslug=$1[L]
```

Which worked perfectly fine.

I then create a static version of that page as it no longer needed to be dynamic and through .htaccess created a 301 redirect.

```
redirect 301 /folder/page-name.php /new-folder/newname.php [L]
```

Works fine – Except, the URL displays the URL slug string.

```
/new-folder/newname.php?urlslug=page-name
```

What would be the best approach to fix this trouble/ strip out ?urlslug=page-name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix mod_rewrite and mod_alias directives in this manner. They're both part of the URL processing pipeline, and thus the different directives will *both* get applied to the *same* request. You should stick with only mod_rewrite in this case:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/page-name.php$ /new-folder/newname.php [L,R=301]
```

And place that **before** the rule that maps to the `/code/page.php` URI.

Comment: Thanks Jon, Your help / insight was very much appreciated.